# Changing CSS styles of specific Javascript-Produced iframe

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe

So I have multiple instances of the following in an html document:

```
<div class="foo">
    <script>javascript that generates: 
        <span class="bar">
            <iframe>iframe contents
            </iframe>
        </span>
    </script>
</div>
```

And the corresponding CSS code:

```
.foo {
}
.bar iframe {
    left: 5% !important; 
    top: 100% !important;
}
```

I need to change the `left` and `top` styles of `.bar iframe` in one instance of the HTML code without modifying the others, and editing anything inside the `<script>` tags is impossible. Is there a way to apply the differing styles using the `<div>` tag?

This problem is confusing to me due to the nested nature of the `.bar iframe` styles. Any suggestions would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily achieve this by adding more details to your CSS selector:

```
.foo .bar iframe{
    left: 10% !important;
    top: 50% !important;
}

.bar iframe {
    position:absolute;
    left: 5% !important; 
    top: 100% !important;
}
```

The more specific selector ".foo .bar iframe" will only select iframes under div's of class "foo". You can play with the exact settings in [my fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/w2Xh2/).

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you want to set specific style to the `iframe` inside the `.foo` element?

Just set the css hierarchy:

```
.foo iframe {
    /*style*/
}
```

It will affect only what is inside the `foo` div.

Answer (score 0):

You can use :nth-child to get the specific instance you want then change the CSS.

```
$(".bar:nth-child(2)").css('top', '20px');
```

http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/